# Как получить список всех подключенных сокетов?

Tags: c#, udp, сокет

Как получить список IP-адресов, подключенных к broadcast IP-адресу по Udp протоколу?

Есть такой код:

```
UdpClient _onlineInformer = new UdpClient() { EnableBroadcast = true, Ttl = 1 };     
_onlineInformer.Connect("192.168.152.255", 0);
```

как может `_onlineInformer` узнать о подключенных сокетах к этому же адресу ?

Comment: @dima_kot, что вы подразумеваете под *подключением по Udp* к *broadcast IP-адресу*? 

Вы наверное хотите узнать все сокеты (в программе?, системе?), которые могут *отправлять* broadcast UDP пакеты? 

Насколько мне известно, для их приема setsockopt(...,SO_BROADCAST,...) делать не надо.

Comment: Отправлять броадкаст пакеты  могут все. Мне нужен список всех адресов подключенных к широковещательному адресу.

Comment: К broadcast **не подключаются**. Если Вы слушаете порт (сделали для udp сокета bind()), то будете читать все пакеты, отправленные на этот порт. Как отправленные конкретно данному **хосту**, так и broadcast. По крайней мере в \*nix.

По поводу "Отправлять броадкаст пакеты могут все" - не знаю, возможно в c# setsockopt(...,SO_BROADCAST,...) делается по умолчанию.

Comment: По поводу "Отправлять броадкаст пакеты могут все" - я не ясно сформулировал. Я сам в коде делаю так  EnableBroadcast = true каждому сокету. 

А задача сводится к тому, что бы получит список сокетов, которые получат пакет отправленный на  бродкаст адрес

Comment: В выводе команды `netstat` для протокола UDP в колонке `'Local Address'` после ':' номер порта. 

В \*nix для получения списка процессов, слушающих UDP можно выполнить `lsof`

     root@avp-xub11:~# lsof -i4UDP
     COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
     avahi-dae 527  avahi   13u  IPv4   7150      0t0  UDP *:mdns 
     avahi-dae 527  avahi   15u  IPv4   7152      0t0  UDP *:46109 
     rpcbind   539   root    6u  IPv4   7200      0t0  UDP *:sunrpc 
     rpcbind   539   root    7u  IPv4   7201      0t0  UDP *:713 
     ....

В колонке NAME есть порт.

Comment: @dima_kot, извините, только сейчас дошло.

Вы хотите получить список всех *хостов в LAN*, на которых слушается заданный порт?

Думаю, без захода на хост (запроса к сервису (при желании его можно напистать тоже на UDP) на хосте) это невозможно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попытаться попинговать Broadcast-адрес, но ответят лишь те хосты, на которых разрешён бродкаст. Если между ними имеются роутеры, на них так же должен быть разрешён бродкаст.

**Дополнение**: В вашем случае можно реализовать собственный легковесный протокол, по которому остальные хосты ответят опрашивающему хосту.